# How do I change the dropEvent behavior correctly?

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to change the default behavior when dropping a file in QtextEdit

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(869, 499)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.textEdit.dropEvent = self.dropEvent
    
    
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            print(event.mimeData().text())
        event.accept()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But after performing dropEvent, the cursor in TextEdit stops moving.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. You're not supposed to edit pyuic files; 2. "monkey-patching" of Qt functions (especially event handlers, and also using methods of non Qt classes) is always discouraged, as you should subclass the Qt widget and override those methods instead; 3. by "the cursor stops moving" do you mean that the program freezes, or that the cursor caret doesn't update/blink anymore?

Comment: The cursor does not update, does not move, does not blink. The program continues to run.
I do not edit pyuic files.  I just made a minimal reproducible example.

I read about overriding dropEvent here https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/dnd.html

Comment: You don't need Designer/pyuic to create a MRE (unless the question *does* relate to Designer), just subclass the widget/container you need and eventually add child widgets to it. That said, the default behavior of QTextEdit requires the default implementation of `dropEvent()` to be called, because of internal flags that *also* properly update the text cursor. If you explain what do you actually want to do in your implementation, it will be easier for us to provide answers.

Comment: I use Qt Designer to create pyuic files.

My task is to get the path of the file into a variable when dropping it into TextEdit. I also don't need to print the path in TextEdit itself (standard behavior), since the file must be displayed in another widget (TextBrowser). And in TextEdit instead of the file path I would like to specify the macro of this file.

Perhaps a screenshot of the interface will clarify
https://mega.nz/file/siIh2ayR#h7GZ-HIAi6g2JiLhDWisysSRnb_B8SQGUu3DtDCWi-c

Comment: With all due respect, what you use for your own project is irrelevant here, the *question* must contain a *valid* MRE, and exclude any other possible cause of issues (which is the case for editing/merging pyuic generated code and monkey-patching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTextEdit uses internal flags (not exposed to the API) that properly update the text cursor during drag and drop operations, mostly to allow pasting in the exact position within the text based on the mouse cursor, and in the meantime show the "cursor caret" to the user so that they will know where the content would be inserted.

This means that the default implementation of QTextEdit `dropEvent()` must **always** be called in order to properly update the cursor.

Now, proper drag&drop implementation of QTextEdit should always be done through [`insertFromMimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData) (and eventually [`canInsertFromMimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#canInsertFromMimeData) to prevent drop at all).

If you want to alter the behavior when dropping certain contents, then just override that function:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class DropEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def insertFromMimeData(self, data):
        if data.hasUrls():
            self.insertPlainText('%ONEFILE%')
        else:
            super().insertFromMimeData(data)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = DropEdit()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, the issue is that `insertFromMimeData()` is called no matter if the operation is done from clipboard (through <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> or via the context menu) or from drag&drop. Another issue is that drag&drop can also happen *within* the text edit, for instance to move a selected text somewhere else.

A basic solution, which would prevent pasting from d&d but *not* from clipboard, would be to use an internal flag that can be set in the `dropEvent()` and would be cleared in `insertFromMimeData()`.

The following example will accept drops only if the dropped data has *no* urls in it, but will still accept pasting from clipboard if it contains urls (for instance, copying an object in the file browser):

```py
class DropEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    acceptDrop = True
    def insertFromMimeData(self, data):
        if self.acceptDrop:
            super().insertFromMimeData(data)
        self.acceptDrop = True

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.acceptDrop = not event.mimeData().hasUrls()
        super().dropEvent(event)
```